# Get indices of elements in tensor a that are present in tensor b

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

For example, I want to get the indices of elements valued 0 and 2 in tensor `a`. These values, (0 and 2) are stored in tensor `b`. I have devised a pythonic way to do so (shown below), but I don't think list comprehensions are optimized to run on GPU, or maybe there is a more PyTorchy way to do it that I am unaware of.

```py
import torch
a = torch.tensor([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2])
b = torch.tensor([0, 2])
torch.tensor([x in b for x in a]).nonzero()

>>>> tensor([[0],
             [2],
             [5],
             [6]])
```

Any other suggestions or is this an acceptable way?

Comment: In numpy I believe you could do this with `np.nonzero(np.isin(a, b))` assuming `a` and `b` were numpy arrays. Unfortunately `isin` isn't currently a pytorch operation though there's an open feature request as well as a suboptimal version that relies on broadcasting provided [in the pytorch issue tracker](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/3025#issuecomment-392601780).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a more efficient way to do it (as suggested in the link posted by jodag in comments...):

```
(a[..., None] == b).any(-1).nonzero()
```

Comment: This is good. `a[..., None]` unsqueezes and transposes vector `a`. `a[..., None] == b` compares each element of `a` transposed with all elements of `b`, generating a boolean matrix for each comparison. `.any(-1)` summarizes comparisons into a vector, using the appropriate dimension, and `nonzero()` transforms the boolean values into indices.

Comment: Shouldn't it be like `(a[..., None] == b).any(-1).nonzero().squeeze()`? Because, otherwise, it adds additional dimension.

Comment: @DmytroSytro I think the answer gives a solution that is exactly like what I posted in my original question, but yes, a redundant dimension is created in both cases and `squeeze()` gets rid of it.